# Use custom control in XML views

Tags: xml, sapui5

How can one use a custom control in an XML view?

I have a control named `foo.bar.MyControl` which extends `sap.m.Button`.

I want to use that control in my XML view:

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <!-- What to type here ??? -->
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:foobar="foo.bar">
  <foobar:MyControl>
    <!-- ... -->
  </foobar:MyControl>
</mvc:View>
```

Namespaces reflect the javascript namespace and `MyControl` is the constructor function.

More about namespaces in XML views: https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/2421a2c9fa574b2e937461b5313671f0

Best Regards,
Tobias